# Change ng-bind-html value using controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-bind-html

I want to change the ng-bind-html vale, but have no idea how to do that.

My initial ng-bind-html vale is :-

```
<p class="forum-content" id="{{post.id}}" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(post.content)|truncate:90"></p>
```

and want this value:

`<p class="forum-content" id="{{post.id}}" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(post.content)"></p>`

after a button being pressed.

Initially it is truncating my data to 90 character and I want to show full data after button being pressed. My main moto is to show full data after button(read-more) being pressed.

Comment: Did you try doing the `truncate` part directly in the `renderHtml` function? Then your button just updates a boolean in the scope, and based on that boolean, `renderHtml` returns the truncated value or not.

Comment: i tried but it dint work.

Comment: $scope.renderHtml = function (html_code) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
  };

this is my renderHtml. Can you suggest me your approach to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple trick:

```
<p class="forum-content" id="{{post.id}}" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(post.content)|truncate:limit"></p>

<button ng-click="showAll()">Show all</button>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.limit = 90;
$scope.showAll = function() {
    $scope.limit = 100000000; // should be large enough not to truncate anything
};
```

This will still try to truncate though. If you really want to avoid it, a cleaner solution is to use the filter in the controller:

```
<p class="forum-content" id="{{post.id}}" ng-bind-html="renderAndTruncateHtml(post.content)"></p>

<button ng-click="showAll()">Show all</button>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.shouldTruncate = true;
$scope.renderAndTruncateHtml = function(value) {
    var result = $scope.renderHtml(value);
    if ($scope.shouldTruncate) {
        result = $filter('truncate')(result, 90);
    }
    return result;
};
$scope.showAll = function() {
    $scope.shouldTruncate = false;
};
```

Comment: One more thing I want to ask.
 I want to show the full content of only specific post. Your solution shows full content of all posts.

Comment: Store the shouldTruncate flag (or the limit, in the first solution) in the post itself, so that each post has its own flag/limit.

Comment: post contains a json data, fetched using API.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Either add this flag when you fetch them, or use a `shouldShowAll` flag instead of a `shouldTruncate`, so if the flag is absent, it's falsy, and the post will be trucated by default.

Comment: can you tell me how to add a flag to the fetched data?

Comment: `posts.forEach(function(post) { post.shouldTruncate = true; });`.

Comment: the way i'm getting the post is this :
in controller i have `$scope.datum` and in html :
`<div ng-repeat="data in datum>
    <div ng-repeat="posts in data.content>
         <div ng-repeat="post in posts>
              <p class="forum-content" id="{{post.id}}" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(post.content)"></p>
</div>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: will you please help me in setting the flag @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

Controller:

```
var truncateText = true;

$scope.renderHtml = function(content){
  // your code here
  return truncateText ? $filter('truncate')(content, 90) : content;
};

$scope.toggleTruncate = function(){
  truncateText = !truncateText;
};
```

View:

```
<p class="forum-content" id="{{post.id}}" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(post.content)"></p>

<button class="button button-block" ng-click="toggleTruncate()">Toggle Truncate</button>
```